# Refreshing modal with form feedback

Tags: django

I'm using a modal for a sign up form in Django. What I want to happen is for input to be checked and the form refreshed to indicate that either the sign up was a success, or to complain about which input is missing or incorrect. So far as I can tell from the code I'm working with, this format would be correct if I was using a regular page, but it doesn't work with the modal. When I click the button, stuff is definitely getting confirmed behind the scenes (and the database is being updated, so all that's good), but nothing is sent back to the page at the end.

```
@requires_csrf_token
def signup(request):
error, success = '', ''

    recap = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
    [ETC]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        [CHECKING INPUTS]

    if not error:
        [OTHER STUFF]
        success = "SUCCESS MESSASGE"

    return render(request, 'signup_modal.html',
        { 'firstname': firstname,
          'lastname': lastname,
          'email': email,
          'phone': phone,
          'error': error,
          'success': success})
```

I'm guessing the issue is here at the end with the return render request bit.

Thanks so much.

ETA:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".submit-signup").on("click", function() {
        var data = $("#signup-form").serialize();
        $.post("/signup/", data, function() {

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Response Tab:

```
<form id="signup-form">

  <input id="id_firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name"
      value="firstname" >
  <input id="id_lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name"
      value="lastname" >  
  <input id = "id_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail"
      value="user@gmail.com" >
      <input id="id_password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input id="id_password_repeat" type="password" name="password_repeat" placeholder="Repeat password">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY"></div>

  <p class="success-message">  </p>
  <p class="error-message">  Couldn't verify reCAPTCHA. Refresh the page and try again?  </p>

  <button type="button" class="submit-signup">Sign up</button>         
  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Try printing out the success/error variables, do you get anything? Check for python console, what is the status code when you POST the form? Any thing?

Comment: Yeah, success and/or error get the expected values. The console says "'POST /signup/ HTTP/1.1' 200 1897" when I click the button.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do if all is going as expected? What do you mean by "nothing is sent back to the page at the end"?

Comment: I need the modal to refresh with the success/error messages. It just sits there doing nothing when I click the button.

Comment: Everything works great if I use a regular webpage, it's just that it's a modal that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons.

1. Your data is not returned as expected.
2. Your xhr call is not replacing the current dom data with the returned data.

From what I make of the question. Your ajax call is not replacing the old dom data with the new data.

In order to verify this. Fire up the chrome console. Go to `Networks` and then hit your signup button. Find the request that is sent. Most probably you're dealing with ajax (xhr) request. Select that request and switch to `Response` tab and check if the data returned is as expected.

Edit after question update:

So, our assumption that the new data is not replaced in dom was correct.

What you need to do is:

- Modify your view to return a json such as `{'status': boolean, 'form': html}`
- Modify your JS to check the returned response's status and update the find the dom div which should be replaced with the html you're returning.

Eg:

View would look something like:

```
def signup(request):
    # do your stuff
    html = render_to_string(YOUR_TEMPLATE, YOUR_CONTEXT)
    response = {'status': true, 'form': html}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

And your JS would contain this inside the ajax call:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response['status'] == 'true') {
        target = $('#FIND_YOUR_MODAL_DIV_BY_ID')
        data = response['form'];
        target.html(data);
    }
}
```

One of the good resources for the thing you're trying to accomplish: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/django-with-ajax-a-modern-client-server-communication-practise/

Comment: The response tab shows everything perfectly. The error message is exactly where it should be in the code. It's just not refreshing the modal itself.

Comment: Can you add the js which makes the ajax call that hits your view and the format of the response you see in the `Response` tab?

Comment: My bad, we have to return JsonResponse from view. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok. So now response is showing the {"status": true, "form": [TEMPLATE WITH INFO FILLED IN]}, but still nothing is being changed in the modal itself.

Comment: Actually, the modal closes and then refuses to open, now when I hit submit. Oh man.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Response` tab is showing the html as you are rendering the data on success, you should use `JsonResponse` in your view to send the data for a response to the AJAX call. Example use `return JsonResponse(data)` on success of the AJAX call.

Let me know if it helps.